# Manage Lists Permission - Create Document Libraries but not edit columns?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions, library

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 to allow users to create lists and libraries, but not allow them to modify the site columns or any other information in Library Settings?
If so, are we able to have a 'default' content type applied to a newly created library or list?

I know that "Manage Lists" offers the ability to create/delete lists and modify their columns, but we have very strict content types set up for project sites and don't want site admins to modify their lists at the column level.

I am looking for a non-programmatic solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could set them up with Manage Lists as the default which would allow creation of new libraries, but break inheritance on existing lists/libraries and remove Manage Lists which would protect them from changes.

I am not aware of any way to automatically change this permission as a list/library is created nor any way to separate out the ability to create lists/libraries from editing columns.